# What is the difference between "New window" and "New private window" in Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox

In Tor Browser's application menu, there is "New window" and "New private window". What is the difference between these two? They appear to have the same effect.

[image: Tor Browser application menu]

(Tor Browser version 11.0.10)

Comment: I'm not sure, but my guess is that it is the same as opening a **new window** and then taking a **new identity** so that cookie files and other cache are not shared between the windows.

Comment: @spykyvenator For both "new window" and "new private window", cookies are shared between the windows.